# How to measure SpannableString height?

Tags: android, text, spannablestring

I have a TextView in which I'm displaying SpannableString with different Span Sizes. I need to know exact height of last word in SpannableString but the method I'm using is getting it wrong. What I am doing wrong?

Here is test code I am using

```
    SpannableStringBuilder spannableString = new SpannableStringBuilder("Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text");
    spannableString.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(10, true), 0, spannableString.length() / 3, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spannableString.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(15, true), spannableString.length()/3, 2 * spannableString.length()/3, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spannableString.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(20, true), 2 * spannableString.length() / 3, spannableString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    surfaceView.setTranslationY(measureSpannableHeight());

private int measureSpannableHeight() {
    StaticLayout staticLayout = new StaticLayout(spannableString, new TextPaint(), 480, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1, 0, false);
    return staticLayout.getHeight();
}
```

(translation of surfaceview is only to illustrate height result of measure method)

Answer (score 0):

Construct a paint object and after setting the equivalent span properties to the paint, you can measure your word height using the following.

```
Paint mTextPaint = new Paint();
mTextPaint.setTextSize(20) // your span size
mTextPaint.setTypeface(typeface)
```

The dimensions of the word will be held in this Rect

```
Rect textBounds = new Rect();

int startIndex = spannableString.length() - 4; //length of your last word as start and end indices.
int endIndex = spannableString.length();
mTextPaint.getTextBounds(spannableString, startIndex, endIndex, textBounds); 

int height = textBounds.height();
```